# TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset' in DecisionTree.trainClassifier in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, decision-tree, azure-databricks

I have written simple code in pyspark on Azure databricks( followed this link
[decision tree in pyspark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html#classification)-)

```
%python
x='x'
z='y'
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,41,2,6,2,3,56,1,2,5,1,2,45,1,3,2], 'b':[x,z,x,x,z,x,z,x,x,x,z,z,x,z,z,x,x,x]})

# Train a DecisionTree model.
model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(data, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},impurity='gini', maxDepth=5, maxBins=32)
```

I have kept parameters as default. While running I get error-

**TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'**

I am not sure which argument this error is referring to and also where do i need to specify my dependent variable in classifier?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `trainClassifier` takes the first parameter to be an RDD. Here, data you have given is a pandas dataframe. You see the error because, `first()` is a method that can be applied on spark objects.

> As per [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree), 
>   Training data: **RDD** of LabeledPoint.
>   Labels should take values {0, 1, …, numClasses-1}.

Hence, convert `data` to RDD, and that should work fine.